# Are there any other Linux distributions that automatically get UEFI right?

Tags: distribution-choice, system-installation, distributions

Recently I've been trying many different linux distros, and the only one that can setup UEFI correctly out of the box is Fedora.

There is 0 tweaking involved. Somehow it just automatically knows if a computer can support UEFI mode or not and automatically sets up the gpt partitions and everything.

Are there any other Linux distros that will also correctly setup UEFI mode upon installation?

Answer (score 2):

I filed a bug report and it has been fixed already for the only issue I ran into on the beta Debian Wheezy installer. The current RC1 and the final release should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Up to February, 2013, I have not found any other than Fedora, to support UEFI boot mode, out of the box, all the other ones, Ubuntu, Debian, kubuntu, Linux Mint, etc. All need to have the kernel recompiled with extra settings and parameters in order to add the UEFI functionality.

Even if you do that, it will not detect automatically what type of boot mode there is, the kernel will just be recompiled for UEFI.

Comment: The Arch vanilla kernel supports UEFI. There is no element of the Arch install that could be described as "automagical" though...

Comment: I'd try OpenSUSE.